# How do I get the View of the SwiftUI Gesture?

Tags: swiftui, gesture

Say I have a several emojis positioned on the screen. Each have a TapGesture recognizer. How do I get the emoji that was tapped?

```
ForEach(self.dataSet.emojis) { emoji in
    Text(emoji)
           .position(self.position(for: emoji, in: geometry.size))
                        .gesture(
                            TapGesture()
                                .onEnded { action in
                                    
                                    // How do I get the view(the tapped emoji)?
                                    })
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/64034217/12299030? Or this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/60353657/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi, it does.